# How can I change the color of the progress bar of a task in Redmine or where is the code located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, gantt-chart, eruby

I want to change the color of the progress bar of a task. I've located the `.erb` source file for the gantt chart page and the `.rb` source code for the computation of `%` done progress but it seems it's not the right file to edit.
[image]

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here. 
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually edit image located at:

```
your_redmine_root/public/images/task_late.png
```

Where `your_redmine_root` is a place where your Redmine is physically installed, and it depends upon underlaying operating system, etc...

So gannt is a combination of html code generated from underlaying RoR application which's view you can edit in `app/views/gantts/show.html.erb`. Javascript code from `public/javascripts/gantt.js` and CSS style (theme), which actually might differ if you are using some custom theme or plugin, at default install it's in `public/stylesheet/application.css`

The particular codes might also be different due to Redmine version, but you are looking for

```
.task_late { background:#f66 url(../images/task_late.png); border: 1px solid #f66; }
```

On Redmine 3.0 it's at line 986. .task_late is ordinary div, and you can set it's css style any way you want...

Don't forget to restart Redmine after editing, and also make sure to refresh your browser's cache.